# Matplotlib で作成する図の書式を一定にしたい

Tags: python, matplotlib

PythonでPlot図を作成したときに、一番左の数字（の桁）により、微妙に上下で図を比べる時に見ずらいです。左側の数字を残しつつ、X座標を基準に上下で図を合わせることは可能でしょうか？

以下にサンプルを添付しておきます。よろしくお願いします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 現状のコードも質問に含めてみてください。

Comment: matplotlib をお使いでしたら、`subplots()` で `sharex=True` を指定するとよいかと思います。`fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)`

Comment: ありがとうございました。plt.subplots内にsharex=Trueを加えることで解決でしました。

Comment: 解決した場合にはコメント欄で終わらせずに、ぜひ個別の回答として投稿してください。